# Evaluate double integral $\iint_A \log(y)\,dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Calculate the double integral

$$\iint_A \log(y)\,dx\,dy$$

Where 
$$ A = \{(x,y)\in R^2 : 0 \leq x \leq 1, \sqrt{x}\leq y \leq \sqrt[3]{x}\}$$

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would invert the inequalities to $y^3\le x\le y^2$ and $0\le y\le 1$, and set up your iterated integral as follows:
\begin{align*}
\iint_A\ln(y)\,dx\,dy
&=\int_0^1\ln(y)\int_{y^3}^{y^2}dx\,dy\\
&=\int_0^1\ln(y)\left(y^2-y^3\right)dy\\
&=\left[\frac{y^4}{16}-\frac{1}{4} y^4 \ln (y)-\frac{y^3}{9}+\frac{1}{3} y^3 \ln(y)\right]_0^1.
\end{align*}
Recall that these are limits, so you might have to use L'Hospital's Rule to evaluate on the lower end.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\iint_A\log(y)dxdy &= \int_0^1\int_{\sqrt x}^{\sqrt[3] x}\log ydydx \\
&= \int_0^1 y(\ln y -1)|_\sqrt x^\sqrt[3] x dx \\
&= \int_0^1 \sqrt[3] x\left(\frac{\ln x}{3} -1\right) - \sqrt x\left(\frac{\ln x}{2} -1\right)
\end{align}

You can do the rest.